# Do you need a program to make a run in Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

The definition for interaction in netrunner seems a tad vague and I was hoping to clear up some points. I know you can run through ice and accept subroutines if you do not have the appropriate ice breaker. You choose not to interact and bypass the ice but suffer the consequences.

Can you still do this if you have no programs installed as the runner? For example, couldn't I, without any programs, make 4 runs on my first turn? Even if the corp put down 3 ice on their turn, Most likely they will not or cannot rez them all. This gives me several, maybe even four succesful runs on my first turn.

Is this possible?

Comment: If the top of R&D is a piece of ice, then four runs on turn 1 isn't going to do much!

Comment: Right but after the first run then you would stop running on R&D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct!  No icebreaker is required to make a run.  So yes, the mantra: run early, run often!  On the first turn, it is usually good to put some pressure on a central server that isn't well defended (either HQ or R&D).

However: some decks will punish you for this (especially Jinteki), as they have cards that can hurt you when accessed from R&D or HQ (Snare, Shock, et cetera).  Also, you can run naked (no ICEBREAKERS) even against servers that have ICE... and you might be successful if the corp doesn't rez them or if they don't have any "end the run" subroutines.  Again, that can be pretty dangerous though (watch out for Neural Katanas).

Most corp players will expect this though - if you are Criminal, they will generally defend HQ on turn 1 (to stop Account Siphons); if you are Shaper, they will typically put some ICE on R&D (to try and prevent Maker's Eye runs).

Comment: Quetzal is a great runner for this because she can get through much of the end the run ice